# Draw an ellipse with only few dynamic points in RaphaelJS

Tags: svg, raphael, ellipse

I'm trying to draw a good looking ellipse using RaphaelJS while only having the coordinates for the top, bottom, left and right points of the ellipse. The following image illustrates better what I need:

[Example showing only the points and then the full ellipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GgB2.gif)

I've tried using most of the the curveto based commands the path method allows but none of them got somewhat close to what I need and frankly I can't wrap my head around the elliptical-arc command (A).

Any way I can work this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use Raphael's ellipse: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ry8kT/122/)**

```
var r = new Raphael(10,10, 500, 500);
var e = r.ellipse(50, 50, 40, 20).attr({fill: 'yellow', stroke:"red"});
```

Here `ellipse(x, y, rx, ry)`

- x coordinate of the centre
- y coordinate of the centre
- horizontal radius
- vertical radius

Hope this is what you wanted.